# what is the result type 3D vector, point and scalar arithmetic operations?

Tags: vectors, coordinate-systems, 3d

I doing programming but I am not good at math.

I want to represent *point* and *vector* in different type. Both *point* and *vector* are tuple of 3 elements, where *point* represent location and *vector* represent direction and magnitude.

Given **P** for *point*, **V** for *vector* and **S** for one dimensional *scalar* type, how they interact each other in arithmetic operations?

By arithmetic operations I mean addition, subtraction, multiplication dan division.

In my understanding, adding or subtract 2 *vectors* will get result as vector.

```
V + V = V
V - V = V
```

but, what about addition or subtraction *vector* with *scalar*? is that make sense?

Multiplication vector with *scalar* have meaning to scale the magnitude of vector, which is give vector as result.

```
V * S = V
```

Subtraction of 2 *points* will result a *vector* between two *points*

```
P - P = V
```

well, that is what I know, I not sure about the other operators.

So, my question is, what is the result type of arithmetic operations of vectors, points and scalars?

```
V + V = V      V + S = ?      V + P = ?
V - V = V      V - S = ?      V - P = ?
V * V = ?      V * S = V      V * P = ?
V / V = ?      V / S = V      V / P = ?

P + V = ?      P + S = ?      P + P = ?
P - V = ?      P - S = ?      P - P = V
P * V = ?      P * S = ?      P * P = ?
P / V = ?      P / S = ?      P / P = ?

S + V = ?      S + S = ?      S + P = ?
S - V = ?      S - S = ?      S - P = ?
S * V = V      S * S = ?      S * P = ?
S / V = V      S / S = ?      S / P = ?
```

**P**: point

**V**: vector

**S**: scalar

**X**: meaningless/not make sense